# Linux shared folder with user retaining write permission

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a test group `d` with 3 users (from /etc.groups `d:x:1004:u1,u2,u3`)

I have created shared folder `/home/test/photos` which is owned by root and group set to d.

I need to allow everyone in group d to write in that folder and read every file but only owner should be allowed to edit/remove the file.

I have tried setgid/setuid but without success.

Comment: If the directory's permissions are 0775 (`rwxrwxr-x`), then group members will be able to create, rename and delete files in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the sticky bit, similar to `/tmp` that has mode `1777`. Setting this bit means that only the owner can rename or remove file.

For the permissions on the files, you must make sure that the group permissions are read only.

If you don't want to modify the users' umask, the use `setfacl` on the directory with the `-d` option:

From `man setfacl`

> -d, --default
>   All operations apply to the Default ACL.

From `man acl`

> In addition, a directory may have an associated ACL that governs the initial access ACL for objects created within that directory; this ACL is referred to as a default ACL.

The default ACL specifies what ACL (access permissions) should be applied to new files and directories within the specified directory.